# How to fix error unable to read font in ImageMagick/Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, fonts, imagemagick

I'm running ImageMagick in WSL Debian and Ubuntu. I'm trying to write some text with ImageMagick but I getting font errors in both WSL linux versions:

```
$ magick -background lightblue -fill blue -font arial -pointsize 72 label:Anthony label.gif

magick: unable to read font arial @ warning/annotate.c/RenderType/1024.
magick: unable to read font arial @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1654.
```

The commands below doesn´t list anything.

```
$ convert -list font
$ identify -list font
$
```

And this others prints

```
$ ls /usr/local/share/fonts/
$ ls /etc/fonts
conf.avail  conf.d  fonts.conf
```

Current IM version. Thanks for any help.

```
$ magick -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-19 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21601 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): fftw freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lzma png tiff webp xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (12.2)
```

Comment: Edit in the contents of your type.xml file, please. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php#fonts to know which one is loaded (also specify that)